# PyGtk3 - Gtk.DrawingArea won't scroll

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, viewport, drawingarea, gtkscrolledwindow

My problem consists in that I have replaced a GtkImage for a GtkDrawingArea widget and it's not scrolling like it happens with the GtkImage.

This is how I place both my GtkImage and GtkDrawingArea (one at a time).

- GtkScrolledWindow

  - GtkViewPort

    - GtkImage / GtkDrawingArea

I thought this would have been enough.

**With the GtkImage:** I scroll horizontally and vertically and the GtkImageViewport loads the part of the PixBuf that should be displayed, as you can see here:

[image]

**With the GtkDrawingArea:** the scroll bars occupy all the available area, so the image *won't move*, as you can see here:

[image]

If I resize the window, the portion of the image that is not visible and should be visible when scrolling appears:

[image]

**NOTE1:** I want to be able to draw on the image and work with the pixels coordinates, that's why I think using Gtk.DrawingArea and Cairo was a good idea.

**NOTE2:** I've tried both through Glade, and through code using scrolledwindow.add_with_viewport(drawing_area)

Comment: I don't have enough information to help you. I suggest you check that the size request of the drawing area is well set to the total area being drawn.

Comment: That was. Do you want to answer so I can make your response selected answer? Basically I added the line    
            self.__w_drawing_area.set_size_request(image.get_width(), image.get_height())

Comment: You should not post the solution in the question. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nico238 suggested out, I was not explicitly requesting the area for the DrawingArea.  I set now the DrawingArea dimensions based on the image I'm drawing.

```
''' 'draw' callback method. '''
def __on_draw_drawing_area(self, widget, cairo_context):

    if len(self.__store) > 0:
        # The PixBuf to draw
        image = self.__store_dictionary[self.__active_sample_id]['displayed_image']
        # This was the missing line.
        self.__w_drawing_area.set_size_request(image.get_width(), image.get_height())
        # Add the image to the Cairo context and draw
        Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cairo_context, image, 0, 0)
        cairo_context.paint()
```